# What does the linear space R^R over R stand for

Tags: linear-algebra

***In a linear algebra problem, the text assumes a linear space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ over the real number field $\mathbb{R}$. I am confused about what it stands for and what it means.***

The complete version of the problem is written like this:

Identify whether the following functions are linearly independent or not on the linear space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ over the real number field $\mathbb{R}$:

$1$, $e^x$, $e^{2x}$, $e^{3x}$, ... , $e^{nx}$.

Comment: The notation can be interpreted as the set of all functions from the reals to the reals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two sets $A,I$, let us introduce the notation
$$
A^I:=\{f:I\to A: f \;\text{is a function}\}.
$$
You can think of $I$ as a set of *indices*.

We observe that a general sequence of real number $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an element of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Similarly, a general function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is an element of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

Hence, you are working with the (real) vector space of all real-valued functions.

For your exercise, having denoted $f_k=e^{kx}$, $k\in\mathbb N$, just try to check if, for a general collection $(\lambda_j)_{j=0}^n\subset \mathbb R$, it holds 
$$
\sum_{j=o}^n \lambda_j f_j = 0\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad \lambda_i=0 \quad \forall\ i\in \{0,\dots,n\}.
$$